# Change de copy, select all and define button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

How can I change the content and implement unique functionality for the "Copy, Select All, Define" buttons?

I need to change the text and functionality of these buttons.
How can I do this?
I don't know what to search for.

Thanks

when I select any text on UITextView show these buttons, And I want to change this buttons and the functions.

Comment: is it just me or this is really not clear at all... I actually don't know what you're talking about.. maybe specify a little bit more ?

Comment: You need to provide much more specific information. Are you talking about changing the title of a `UIButton` or something else? Is this something you want to do in code while the app is running or something you want to change in Interface Builder? We need details.

Comment: when I select any text on UITextView show these buttons, And I want to change this buttons and the functions.

Answer (score 0):

`UIMenuController` is i think what you need.  Check it out in Apple's docs.  You can create your own menu items and implement your own functionality for them.

Comment: Sorry, just do a search on UIMenuController class documentation.  Removed link.

Comment: Your added menu items can be whatever you like, but they will be added after the system ones.  Not sure if this is what you want and i'm not sure you can remove the system ones from the menu.

Comment: I want to select some text on my UITextView and show the menu and this menu will show the options: "Share text", "send e-mail about text".